# How to indent CLion

Tags: indentation, clion

Hi I am a new user of CLion. The IDE is very good yet I meet a problem about indent. My function code style likes this:

```
void innerFunc()

{

int n = 100;

for(int i = 0; i<n; ++i)
{

do something;

do something;

}

if(something)

{

do one here;

}

else

{

do something else;

}  
}
```

Since my coding habit, I would like to put the left curly brace in the new line, but CLion cannot automatically indent the function content after first {, and also it cannot automatically indent "for" and "if" blocks. I believe somewhere in the setting can be setted to fix this, but I don't know where. Anyone can help? Many thanks!

Comment: I wrapped it in a code block, please re-indent it the way you'd like it to appear. (Er, at least two people did at the same time :) )

Comment: Thanks for the quick replay! e...what does that mean? Wrapped it in a code block and re-indent? don't understand :(

Comment: Did you get an answer on that? Even new lines are not indenting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked CLion settings?
You can configure your [code style](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/configuring-code-style.html).